# Artifactory JAR signing virtual repo not caching local snapshot repo

Tags: artifactory

I have a local Artifactory server that has a bunch of local repositories defined. I've set up a virtual repository and configured it to sign any JAR files that are retrieved through it.

The `libs-signed` virtual repository is connected to `libs-staging-local` and `libs-snapshot-local` so you can fetch any jar from those two repositories and have them signed by our certificate.

If I fetch a JAR from the staging repo via the signing virtual repo, the first time I have to wait until the signing process is finished but any request after that for the same artifact is fast due to the virtual repository cache.

However, if I fetch a JAR from the snapshot repository via the signing virtual repo, I always get that waiting time while the JAR is being signed (and I've verified that the jarsigner process is fired up on the server every time). So signed artifacts that originate from the snapshot repository are not being cached. I've made sure that there aren't any new snapshot versions being added between the two fetches so the original (unsigned) files are exactly the same.

Does anybody know what's going on with that? How can I have the virtual repository cache the signed snapshot JARs?

Comment: Are you creating unique or non-unique snapshots?

Comment: If by non-unique you mean whether we have multiple JARs for the same version number (eg. 5.25-SNAPSHOT) then yes. If I go into the Artifactory UI I can see 10 JARs behind that version (each marked with a timestamp). However, I would have expected Artifactory to cache nevertheless if you fetch the same JAR twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Caching behavior depends on how the non-unique snapshot is being resolved.
If the snapshot is being resolved by requesting the concrete timestamped artifact the signed .jar will be cached, for example:

```
http://localhost:8081/artifactory/libs-snapshot/org/jfrog/test/multi1/3.5-SNAPSHOT/multi1-3.5-20170105.183200-4.jar
```

However if the snapshot is resolved by requesting - the signed .jar will not be cached, for example:

```
http://localhost:8081/artifactory/libs-snapshot/org/jfrog/test/multi1/3.5-SNAPSHOT/multi1-3.5-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

The reason is that the returned artifact for such a request may change and by caching it, Artifactory might return a wrong Artifact.

Comment: Doesn't actually solve my problem but it looks like this answer is "correct". However, Artifactory should be able to realize whether the artifact behind the non timestamped artifact URL has been requested before and retrieved (and therefore cached). I'm disappointed that it doesn't.